# Generic type 'AppsList' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)

Tags: typescript

Have this interface of array of Objects as follows.

```
export interface App {
    entry: object;
    content: {
        label: string;
        visible: boolean;
    };
    name: string;
    length: number;
}

export type AppsList<Response> = App[];
```

What I am trying to do is have AppsList extend Response since Response type is required below.

But I get the error: Generic type 'AppsList' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)

```
export function getLocalApps(userPrefsAppOrder: string): Promise<unknown> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetchLocalApps()
            .then((res: AppsList) => {
                resolve(orderApps(filterInternalApps(res.entry), userPrefsAppOrder));
            })
            .catch(e => reject(e));
    });
};
```

Comment: Why is `AppsList` declared with the `Response` generic parameter? You don't use it in the `AppList` type, and you don't seem to want to provide it when you use it. All that indicates it should just be `type AppsList = App[];`. What am I missing?

Comment: res.entry will give the following. `Property 'entry' does not exist on type 'Response'.ts(2339)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the `<Response>` generic type parameter in your type, and you don't want to seem to want to pass it in, so I think you can safely remove that.

```
export type AppsList = App[];
```

---

But now you get a different problem:

> Property 'entry' does not exist on type 'Response'.ts

You get this error because `AppList` is an array type as denoted byt the `[]` in `App[]`

That declares `AppList` as an array where every element of that array is of type `App`.

So you need to access and *element* of that array before you can access the `entry` property on one of those elements.

For instance:

```
.then((res: AppsList) => {
  resolve(res[0].entry);
})
```

You probably want more than the first element of that array, so you don't want to literally use this code as is, but it illustrates that you want to get one element of the array before you trying to fetch the properties of items in that array.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=15&pln=18&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJAzAAsAZHMKCAQQAdaBnACgEoAueABRhwFssGIADxRUATwB8AWABQskAA9aOGBnhZUGEDERQwCOrXgBvWfHPwQmmGI44ARgCtwGANxmLYPFs0dTMi0D4aHsQCA4GDBgNAHN3AKDzADcBLHsIEA57HBwM0XjAgF8Ci1QoXkz4SOjUOI9zDNqMYg5UZF5QmHjC2XklFTUMMVoDegZSATUAXnhDAG0AXXi+5VUkNExcfBjCckoaMaZkQRhuEEQGQwB5GFAYCKjY9i4efkEhNABrVBwAd1QJCZ6vA4BhkDB8KgQL8XnwBCAmEw4AxckkQAAaEEgZyYFjwKaA-yJcyIQgkPZUQzMFjA4nwAB0zSsiORHCpE0ieIJQISdMSyNRCORcwADAt6VYomIWCU+fBCjTeXz6ZQiMQmAhuXAcRgNSwZcCFd1XEA)

---

> I am trying to have `AppList` extend Response while also being of `App[]` type

You can use an intersection operator `&` to merge types. For example:

```
export type AppsList = Response & App[];
```

Then you can treat as a `App[]` or a `Response`:

```
.then((res: AppsList) => {
  res[0].entry // works as an array of type: App[]
  res.body // a property from the type: Response
  resolve(res[0].entry);
})
```

This is a bit odd though, as creating a value that matches this type would be tricky. But without knowing more about your goal it's hard advise more.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=15&pln=18&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJAzAAsAZHMKCAQQAdaBnACgEoAueABRhwFssGIADxRUATwB8AWABQskAA9aOGBnhZUGEDERQwCOrXgBvWfHPwQmmGI44ARgCtwGANxmLYPFs0dTMi0D4aHsQCA4GDBgNAHN3AKDzADcBLHsIEA57HBwM0XjAgF8Ci1QoXkz4SOjUOI9zDNqMYg5UZF5QmHjC2XklFTUMMVoDegZSATUAXngAJRAGZVRBeAAyeEMAbQBdeL7lVSQ0TFx8GMJyShoxpmRBGG4QRAZDAHkYUBgIqNj2Lh5+IIhGgANaoHAAd1QEhM9XgcAwyBg+FQIAh-z4AhATCYcAYuSSIAANPCQM5MCx4FMYf5EuZEIQSJcqIZmCw4XT4AA6ZpWHF4jisiaRSnU2EJTmJPGbAAM2y5ViiYngAHoVfAISoQQx4FAdaJdTAYFBlThEPAhiNBfQdhzJeY8VzssBlWrdfBaDwRqplYgARbiAhLZV5os8II7fa8QTsdK5QrrGIWCV7YV2RLJVzKERiEwEGK4OSMHmWMm4Wnuq4gA)

Comment: Correct this is the problem and as you said I obviously dont want to only pass [0] of the array, which is why I am trying to have AppList extend Response while also being of App[] type so that it solves the Response issue as well and containing the entry property of App

Comment: I think you want `Response & App[]`? See my update, but if you still have questions, be very specific and support it with a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am only trying to pass the array of Apps which is AppsList which would be res.entry not res[0].entry. Using Response & App[] sounds like it would work but i get the following Property 'entry' does not exist on type 'AppsList'.(2339)